# how to wrap the JFrame so that it fits all my buttons and attach evenlistener to these buttons in Java?

Tags: java, swing, button, resize, jframe

I have the following code, where I make buttons for each alphabets and I want to listen which alphabet is clicked. I have created the buttons. but I have two issues, the buttons overflow the frame, and I have to manually resize the frame to see all the buttons. I used setSize for JFrame, but it still did not fit the frame as I expected.

I also want to attach eventlistner to each buttons, as I make them and get the button name (alphabet) when it is clicked.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HangmanGUI {


        public static void main(String[] args){

            new HangmanGUI();

        }
        //constructor for Hangman
        /**
         * Instantiates a new hangman gui.
         */
        public HangmanGUI() {

            JFrame myframe= new JFrame();
            JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

            myframe.setSize(600,400);

            for (char alphabet = 'A';alphabet<='Z';alphabet++){
                myPanel.add(new JButton(alphabet+""));
            }

            myframe.add(myPanel);
            myframe.pack();
            myframe.setTitle("Hangman Game");
            myframe.setVisible(true);
            myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

}
```

Any other better way or some bad style here -- kindly point out. Thanks a ton

Comment: *"I also want to .."*  A question should be specific, not a shopping list of desires.  You have an answer now to the main question, please accept it and ask another in regard to the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want to attach eventlistner to each buttons, as I make them and
>   get the button name (alphabet) when it is clicked.

If the behavior will be the same for all your buttons, then implement a single [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) as follows:

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton pressedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            String buttonsName = pressedButton.getName();
            String buttonsText = pressedButton.getText();
            // do something with those
        }
    }
};

JButton a = new JButton("A");
a.addActionListener(actionListener);
JButton b = new JButton("B");
b.addActionListener(actionListener);
....
```

**Note:** suggested reading: [EventObject.getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

> the buttons overflow the frame,

The default layout manager for a JPanel is a FlowLayout so the button flow off the panel.

Instead use a `GridLayout` so you can control how many buttons are displayed on each line.

> I used setSize for JFrame, but it still did not fit the frame as I expected.

The pack() undoes the setSize(). It is better to use pack() instead of setSize() and let the layout managers do their job.

Comment: I removed pack() and it works fine as I expected. but you mention to use `GridLayout`. why is that? and including `GridLayout` would involve specifying `gridx, gridy` for each of the buttons correct?

Comment: @user1988876 `setSize()` will be useful, but you might want to consider `setBounds()` which lets you specify the top left corner of the frame; not only the size. If you don't care, then `setSize()` is better.

Comment: `I removed pack()` that is NOT what I suggested!!! The proper way to build a GUI is to use pack() and let the layout managers do their job. `would involve specifying gridx, gridy for each of the buttons` -No, that is GridBagLayout. Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: @gangqinlaohu, don't use setSize(). I do no recommend that in my answer, in fact I recommend against using it.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. However, `setBounds()` does allow a programmer to specify the location and size of a JFrame.